# Intercom react native integration, Android fail to build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build.gradle, google-play-services, intercom

Recently integrate [@intercom/intercom-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@intercom/intercom-react-native) in a react native project, there after when I try to build for android, it failed, as I'm getting the error:

```
    Execution failed for `enter code here`task ':app:mergeExtDexWatuDebug'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:watuDebugRuntimeClasspath'. > Failed to transform play-services-measurement-api-21.4.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:21.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/emmanueltochukwu/.gradle/caches/transforms-`enter code here`3/fceb8847abe1dd3732979c14af3f21a7/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.4.0-runtime.jar. > Error while dexing. > Failed to transform play-services-measurement-api-21.4.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:21.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/emmanueltochukwu/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fceb8847abe1dd3732979c14af3f21a7/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.4.0-runtime.jar.
```

Any solution to resolving this will be appreciated.

I have try making modification to the google service version right within gradle.build

```
   dependencies {
        ...
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15')
        // classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.